# Get the parent directory of a given file

Tags: shell, directory, filenames, variable

Suppose `file` stores the pathname of a non-dir file.

How can I get its parent directory?

why does the following way by appending `/..` to its value not work

```
$ cd $file/..   
cd: ./Tools/build.bat/..: No such file or directory
```

Thanks.

Comment: Example of such a pathname?

Comment: dirname may be what you want

Comment: @schaiba `./Tools/build.bat` as in the example

Comment: Do you ever search before asking or ask basic questions just for the upvotes? It's hard to believe you couldn't find this doing a little searching.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming

```
$ file=./Tools/build.bat
```

With [a POSIX compatible shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) (including zsh):

```
$ echo "${file%/*}"
./Tools
```

With [`dirname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html):

```
$ echo "$(dirname -- "$file")"
./Tools
```

(at least GNU `dirname` takes options, so the `--` is required in case the path starts with a dash.)

Comment: Thanks. why does the following way by appending /.. to its value not work

Comment: okay, I see it is because $file isn't a directory

Comment: Do you really need the `echo`?

Comment: Just a note: I use `dirname` all the time, as I find it more expressive.

Comment: @gardenhead, only for demonstration.  Of course really we'd just do `somecommand "${file%/*}"` (And even for printing, `printf` would arguably be better.)

Answer (score 9):

If you are using `zsh` try `:h` modifier

```
cd $file:h
```

You can add *n* of them to go *n* levels up in directory structure.

Comment: Also works in `csh`/`tcsh` where it comes from though in those shells, you'll need to add a `:q` to account for directory names that contain blanks or wildcards.

Answer (score 6):

this is quite simple with the command dirname, just do the folowing:

```
cd "$(dirname -- "$file")"
```

now you can even go further on this

```
file=/home/switch87/.bashrc
cd "$(dirname -- "$file")"
cd "$(dirname -- "$file")"/..
```

first cd will get you to /home/switch87, the seccond to /home

Answer (score 4):

get the directory of the file in a very general way (when file is known with a relative or absolute pathname, or no path at all):

```
the_dir="$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "${filename}")" && pwd)"
```

So to get the parent of that directory:

```
the_parent_dir="$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "${filename}")/.." && pwd)"
```

cd -P : print the "real" (physical) path, instead of a path using symbolic links. If you take the `-P` out it also works, but you may get a different result ( for exemple:  `cd / ; ln -s /long/path/here  shortcut ; cd shortcut ; pwd` will show you the path: `/shortcut`, whereas if you added `-P` to `cd` you would see `/long/path/here` instead)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use a combination of `readlink` and `dirname`.

```
parent=$(readlink -f "$(dirname "$file")")
cd $parent
```

`dirname` cuts the filename from the path and `readlink -f` turns `$path/..` into a canonical path.

Comment: That potentially gives a different path to the directory, which may not be desirable.